# Why does IE change the color?

Tags: colors, internet-explorer-7, blending

I've placed an image on top of a div.  I'm trying to blend the image into the div (The div is a solid color).  In Google Chrome, it looks great!  The colors blend perfectly.  In IE 7, however, the colors show a hard line even though they should be the same color!  After some examination (a print screen put into paint.net to check the actual RGB values), IE 7 is actually lightning up my image.

The blend has to look seamless.  Google Chrome was fine with this thus far.  Any ideas why IE 7 wont display the color right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The two browsers are using different rendering engines. There are minor differences between them in how they render graphics, particularly jpegs.

The differences are minor but unavoidable.

Most of the time it goes unnoticed; it only makes an appearance in cases like yours when you try to position it against an element with a solid background colour that is supposed to be the same.

You may be able to resolve the issue by using a different image format. Try saving the image as a PNG. PNGs tend to be rendered more accurately between the browsers than jpegs, so that might be enough to solve your problem.

If that doesn't solve your problem, you could try using PNGs alpha transparency feature to produce an image with a fade to transparent at the edge, and then overlap the background colour behind it. This will definitely give you a smooth transition, but is a bit more technical, so harder to achieve. It will also give you problems with older versions of IE (IE6 for sure, I think you'll be okay with IE7), as they had some major bugs with PNG transparency. (If this is an issue for you, there are work-arounds for this; google IEPNGFix for more)